# What sipstack is most .Net friendly?

Tags: .net, voip, sip

I'm looking for a sip stack that can be used in .Net to create a pbx. Are there any other than these two:

- http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SIP_stack_with_SIP_proxy.aspx

If not, are there any .net wrapper (to create a pbx, not a ua) available to a c/c++ stack?

If not, which stack would you create a wrapper for, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to write a PBX when there are so many available?  Asterisk is the first one that comes to mind, but there are Yate, CallWeaver, and a bunch more.

Are you looking for a proprietary stack or an open-source stack?

Comment: "Why" doesn't matter. Open source is the flavor I love.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to develop a PBX you'll need media processing capabilities and as far as the sipsorcery stack goes I can tell you that it doesn't have any since I wrote it.

I'd recommend having a look over another codeplex project called [Call Butler](http://callbutler.codeplex.com/). It's not under active development anymore as far as I can see but it is more of a fully fledged PBX and is at least partially written in .Net. I think that project may have used some 3rd party libraries for bits and pieces so be aware that you may find some ommissions if you're after the full source code.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of .NET libraries are wrappers around existing C++ libraries (e.g. PJSIP). There are some that are fully managed:

Konnetic povide fully managed SIP components for .NET development. They have [.NET SIP](http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx) SDK available.

Otherwise, Microsoft's Lync server comes with a very good managed SIP library, available here:
www.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/default.aspx

Comment: The only wrapper I've found for pjsip is to build user agents (sipeksdk). You know of any other wrappers which can be used to build servers?

Comment: http://voipcore.com/ and http://voipsipsdk.com appear to have spammed most sites and use C++ libraries underneath - but not pjsip. Have you thought about using a managed solution, either Java or .NET?